# PyCharm - colored output in django console

Tags: django, pycharm

The problem is that when I'm lauching dev-server through Kubuntu's Konsole app, debug output is colored:
[image: Konsole.png]

But wher I'm launching it trough built-in "Run" or "Debug" in PyCharm, the output in PyCharm's console is all red:
[image: PyCharm.png]

Is there a way to make output in PyCharm colored? Because I can't find anything related in Settings.

UPD: link to issue on PyCharm issue tracker

As I see some people woting on this question, so here is the link to this issue on PyCharm issue tracker - [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19790](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19790). If you will vote for this feature, it will be released faster!

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-color-scheme-for-consoles.html

Comment: @MaximeB Yes, I saw this tab in settings, but as far as I understood, it interprets all input as "Bad command of file name" or "Log error". The point is I didn't configured anything in Konsole app, it was colored at the beginning. And I think this means that it connects some king of config  for colored output by default, and PyCharm don't do this for some reason.

Comment: Maybe the PC console is too 'basic' to display it this way... Never bothered me tho.

Comment: I agree, 'too basic' doesn't cover it here. It is using the error coloring. This is confusing and bad.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote a code snippet that does the thing for me. It's not a perfect solution, but does the trick. [BSD License](https://lab.it.hs-hannover.de/lukyanch/pydevutils/blob/master/LICENSE)

To use it:

- Option 1: [git clone/download this](https://lab.it.hs-hannover.de/lukyanch/pydevutils/blob/master/colored_logger.py) and import it somewhere (e.g. django development settings). Read the module docstring and the [readme](https://lab.it.hs-hannover.de/lukyanch/pydevutils/tree/master) for details.
- Option 2: include the code snippet below into your django development/debug settings (or anywhere else, where it will be run early). It's automatically verified with SHA-2 against file changes.

```
try:  # Colored logger CaaS. Auto downloaded and verified.
    import os
    import hashlib
    from urllib import request
    url, sha256 = "https://lab.it.hs-hannover.de/lukyanch/pydevutils/raw/c531eaf7/colored_logger.py", "083e1a39cfdbe17a7126188b5477fb8f324be8106a39ed4a00faeb3f18c5aedc"
    cached_file = "/tmp/{0}.py".format(sha256)
    code = bool(os.path.exists(cached_file) or [request.urlretrieve(url, cached_file), print("Downloaded: " + url)]) and open(cached_file, "r").read()
    assert hashlib.sha256(code.encode()).hexdigest() == sha256, os.remove(cached_file) or "Bad content: " + cached_file
    exec(code)
except Exception as e:
    print("No colored logger: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}".format(e=e))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"grep console" is the plugin which handles this perfectly:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console

Comment: How do you configure it?

Comment: Click the grep console icon (red pen). In the "highlighting" section click "Add new item"  add a regular expression to filter for a certain pattern (eg .*ERROR.*). The on this new line select background or foreground and choose the colors you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the development console for PyCharm is not using the same kind of standards to display colors as your normal shell terminal (they are two very different things).

The output console for PyCharm is just a display of commands (its not a full shell with all the bells and whistles of your local terminal emulator).

You can embed a terminal into PyCharm (see the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html) on how to set it up) but doing so will not allow you to redirect the output of the built-in run commands to the terminal window. It will enable you to run arbitrary shell commands there, and avoid having to switch over to a terminal console.

Keep in mind if you have any special shell customization or fonts/glyphs these may not appear correctly in the embedded terminal, because it is using a different set of fonts and configuration.

You can try and raise this as an enhancement at the [PyCharm bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY); if it gets enough votes it may make it in to the next release.

Comment: I don't see this as a direct answer. The issue isn't that the console isn't capable of displaying colors. The issue is that it treats all output as error. The text when starting to run is not red, so it can display at least 2 states and error is not correct.